# How do you read Cookies from the response of an HTTP Outbound Endpoint in Mule?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

The documentation makes posting cookies rather clear, but it does not provide an example of how to read cookies from an incoming response on an outbound http endpoint in Mule.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference

How is this done?  I can see a Set-Cookies header that is an object reference, but I don't see any easy way to get at the contents in this object via Mule Expression Language.

Answer (score 2):

Use the cookie helper class in a custom java message processor
http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/http/CookieHelper.html

because of how cookies are handled in Mule it just handle Cookies as if they were only name/value pairs. You will receive all the cookies that were sent to the inbound flow as if they were their own.